# Название напитков и продуктов при передаче на письме разговорной речи

Tags: прописная-строчная

Добрый день. Вопрос о правильности употребления кавычек и прописных/строчных букв в таком, например, предложении: Они выпили по две "Балтики"-трешки, потом по "Холстену", заели всё роллтонами (имеются в виду продукты фирмы "Роллтон"), сбегали ещё за "Балтикой"-девяткой, а потом уже открыли и "Абрау-Дюрсо".

Answer (score 3):

Если обобщить и систематизировать информацию, содержащуюся в словаре Розенталя по этой теме, то можно получить следующее.

Часть имен собственных можно выделить в одну тематическую группу с общими правилами написания. Это названия средств транспорта, названия растений и животных, а также названия вин, продуктов. Для них выбор формы написания зависит от влияния различных факторов, в том числе от стиля речи.

В этом случае можно выделить 4  формы написания: Форма  1. Прописная буква, без кавычек (в специальной литературе). Форма  2. Прописная буква с кавычками (основная форма). Форма  3. Строчная буква с кавычками.Форма  4. Строчная буква без кавычек.

Формы 3  и  4  фактически относятся к нарицательным существительным.Наличие кавычек в форме 3 говорит о том, что данное слово не является общепринятым термином.

ПРИМЕРЫ

1. Названия сортов вин и минеральных вод пишутся со строчной буквы без кавычек (ФОРМА 4):  кагор, мадера, портвейн, рислинг,  шампанское; нарзан, ессентуки.Вино мадера не допускалось в Европу, чтобы не создавать конкуренции. Эталонным считается рислинг, изготовленный в долине реки Рейн. В бассейны подавался холодный проточный нарзан.
2. Названия марок вин в специальной литературе пишутся с прописной буквы без кавычек   (ФОРМА 1): десертное вино Цинандали.Ассортимент белых сухих вин: Цинандали, Рислинг, Алиготе.
3. Прописная буква с кавычками (ОСНОВНАЯ ФОРМА).Условные названия вин и минеральных вод заключаются в кавычки, первое слово пишется с прописной буквы (ФОРМА 2): Венгерский город  Эгер  славится легендарным вином «Бычья кровь». Минеральная вода «Боржоми» обладает уникальными свойствами.
4. Такая же запись (кавычки и первая прописная буква, ФОРМА 2) используется для названий конфет, колбас и др.:  конфеты «Мишка на Севере», масло «Слобода».

НАШ ПРИМЕР

Применяя вышеизложенные правила, можно остановиться на следующем варианте:Они выпили по две "Балтики"-трешки, потом по "Холстену", заели всё "роллтонами", сбегали ещё за "Балтикой"-девяткой, а потом уже открыли и "Абрау-Дюрсо". Для слова "роллтонами"  использованы кавычки (форма 3), так как это не общепринятое наименование продукта, да еще в форме мн.числа.